# SQL DISTINCT INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN and .NET C# PrimaryKey

Tags: sql, primary-key, left-join, distinct, inner-join

I have 3 tables A, B, and C. I want to get the subId and text for each id. I also want to know IF the id has some eId linked to it.

I've used INNER JOIN on A and B and then LEFT JOIN'd that result with tabel C. My SQL string so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id,A.subId, B.text, C.eId
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id=B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON A.id=C.id
WHERE B.text='something'
```

The problem is that C.eId has multiple entries for each id. So I'm getting output like this:

```
=================================
  id  |  subId  |  text  |  eId  
  1        e12     etc       
  2        e12     etc       
  2        t23     etc     p1111
  3        e12     etc       
  4        e12     etc     p1234
  4        e12     etc     p4325
```

I want to remove the lines like the last one ("4 e12 etc p4325") because I already know that 4, e12 has some other eId linked to it. I need id and subId to be PrimaryKeys.

How do I do this? DISTINCT worked until I added multiple id's to an eId.

**Edit**: I use MSSQL if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall if it works this way, try it and tell me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id,A.subId, B.text,
(select top 1 C.eId from C where C.id = A.id) AS eId
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id=B.id
WHERE B.text='etc'
```

Comment: @JoenJ.Olsen try it again. If it works, don't forget to [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: It worked if I removed the #A, #B and #C. Thank you! :) I'll come back when I get the 15 reputation to vote you up :)

Comment: @JoenJ.Olsen ups, I was testing :P